# How about giving badges to people coming back after long suspensions?

Tags: discussion, badges, account-suspension

I think, if somebody gets a long "free time", and then comes back, and posts again - either here, and to the meta site, it is a clear signature of improvement.

My idea is to giving them some badge for that.

[image]

Comment: I wonder how many people would *try* to get suspended to earn this badge

Comment: How does simply _coming back_ indicate _"improvement"_? They could even start with a rant at their specific meta site.

Comment: @user0042 Coming back, *and* posting with positive score to both the meta and to the main site. Maybe you should have read the whole post before clicking down.

Comment: @HarryVervet :-) There are always badges what can't be reached.

Comment: @peterh Banned people would be coming back with the same score as they had before the ban and recalculated with all the votes they've received during the ban. So what exactly in that process would you count for **improvement** (because there weren't any actions of the OP involved during the ban)?

Comment: @user0042 Your first sentence is irrelevant - the whole post is about badges, not from reputation. Improvement means the improvement in their behavior, not in their skills. [More details here.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would never implement a badge that could only be obtained by a user who did something wrong and got suapended for it. You'd essentially be giving users a badge for being suspended because at some point they're going to do something positive on the site. We already have badges that are awarded for positive behavior irrespective of their past suspension status.